# Rigorous error bounds for polynomial regression

Tags: polynomials, regression, approximation-theory

Consider a set of $N$ points $(x_i , y_i)$. I want to find a $d$ degree polynomial $P_d(x)$ that will minimize the error,
$$ e_d = max_{i \in [N]} ~|P_d(x_i) - y_i| $$

The question I have is about upper bounds on the optimal value of $e_d$, i.e.

$$e_d^* =  min_{P_d \in \Pi_d}~ max_{i \in [N]} ~|P_d(x_i) - y_i| . $$

where $\Pi_d$ is the set of degree $d$ polynomials. Obviously $e^*_N = 0$. But how does $e^*_d$ scale with general $d$?

Considering the practical importance of this question and also the considerable amount of work on polynomial approximation of functions I am guessing that this question has a well defined answer. But I haven't been able to find any good references for this.

Comment: [Best approximation polynomial](http://home.iitk.ac.in/~sghorai/TEACHING/MTH308/minimax.pdf)

Comment: But how does the error scale with the degree? And how does this work for a discrete set of points as in the question?

Comment: The litterature on the question is large. However, while I’m not an expert on the question the « best approximation » polynomials for the $\sup$ norm are rarely used in practical applications as they oscillate a lot as the degree of polynomial increases. The article I provided is more for you to Google the keywords that are inside,